# Passing POSIXct object to function returns numeric vector

Tags: r, vector, numeric, posixct, coercion

I'm trying to do some manipulation on the `POSIXct` vector, but when I pass it to a function, the vector changes into a `numeric` vector, instead of retaining `POSIXct` class, even when the function itself only returns the object:

```
# Sample dates from vector and it's class.
> dates <- as.POSIXct(c("2012-02-01 12:32:00", "2012-10-24 17:25:56", "2008-09-26 17:13:31", "2011-08-23 11:11:17,", "2015-09-19 22:28:33"), tz = "America/Los_Angeles")
> dates
[1] "2012-02-01 12:32:00 PST" "2012-10-24 17:25:56 PDT" "2008-09-26 17:13:31 PDT" "2011-08-23 11:11:17 PDT" "2015-09-19 22:28:33 PDT"
> class(dates)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
# Simple subset is retaining original class.
> qq <- dates[1:5]
> qq
[1] "2012-02-01 12:32:00 PST" "2012-10-24 17:25:56 PDT" "2008-09-26 17:13:31 PDT" "2011-08-23 11:11:17 PDT" "2015-09-19 22:28:33 PDT"
> class(qq)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
# sapply on the same subset using simple "return" function changes class to "numeric" - why? How to retain "POSIXct"?
> qq2 <- sapply(dates[1:5], function(x) x)
> qq2
[1] 1328128320 1351124756 1222474411 1314123077 1442726913
> class(qq2)
[1] "numeric"
```

Why it happens? How can I retain the `POSIXct` class of the original vector? I know that `POSIXct` **is** `numeric` under the hood, but I want to retain the original class for readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lapply` instead of `sapply` as `sapply` by default has the option `simplify = TRUE`.  So, if the `list` elements are of the same length, it will simplify it to `vector` or `matrix` depending on the length of the `list` elements and `POSIXct` is stored as `numeric`.

```
lst <- lapply(dates, function(x) x)
```

If we need to use `sapply`, then an option would `simplify = FALSE`

```
lst <- sapply(dates, function(x) x, simplify=FALSE)
```

After applying the function, if we need as a vector output,

```
do.call("c", lst)
```

Regarding the change of timezone, it is documented in the `?DateTimeClasses`

> Using c on "POSIXlt" objects converts them to the current time zone,
>   and on "POSIXct" objects drops any "tzone" attributes (even if they
>   are all marked with the same time zone).

So, the possible option would be (as mentioned in the comments by @kmo)

```
.POSIXct(lst, tz = "America/Los_Angeles")
#[1] "2012-02-01 12:32:00 PST" "2012-10-24 17:25:56 PDT" "2008-09-26 17:13:31 PDT" "2011-08-23 11:11:17 PDT" "2015-09-19 22:28:33 PDT"
```

Or as @thelatemail mentioned in the comments

```
.POSIXct(sapply(dates,I), attr(dates,"tzone") )
```

Comment: @kmo I think you may have to specify the timezone with `tz`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I noticed one thing though - after converting to vector the timezone is changed to the local one: `> do.call("c", lapply(dates[1:5], function(x) x))
[1] "2012-02-01 21:32:00 CET"  "2012-10-25 02:25:56 CEST" "2008-09-27 02:13:31 CEST" "2011-08-23 20:11:17 CEST" "2015-09-20 07:28:33 CEST"`. Any idea on that one?

Comment: @kmo In my system, your original dates have `PST ` and `PDT` as time zone.

Comment: Yes, original ones do have "PST/PDT", but after `do.call("c", lst)` tz is changed to my local timezone, which is "CEST/CET" - I wonder why that happens and how to mitigate this issue.

Comment: `.POSIXct(lst, tz = "America/Los_Angeles")` brings back the proper timezone, but still don't know why local timezone is used upon vector conversion.

Comment: @thelatemail THanks for that.  Why do you need `dates[0]`? `.POSIXct(c(sapply(dates, I) ), attr(dates,"tzone") )` seems to work for me.

Comment: @akrun - I think i've out-tricked myself - I should go to bed! - just `.POSIXct(sapply(dates,I), attr(dates,"tzone") )` will do fine.